# Impact of UTF-16 on debugging .NET in WinDbg?

Tags: .net, windbg, sos

.NET uses UTF-16 to represent strings, which is usually 2 bytes per character.

Many debugging tricks (including my own answers) will use the output of `!do` to get the address of the first character and then use the string length*2 in order to get the end address of the string.

Some examples where this can be useful:

- `du` to dump the string, because `!do` will not dump the complete string
- `.writemem` to [write strings to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20343045/how-to-dump-string-using-windbg-poi-function/20518579#20518579) so that it can be processed by other tools
- `s` to [search for strings containing specific substrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380787/windbg-how-can-i-dump-strings-which-match-a-given-filter/20809131#20809131)

However, UTF-16 also has 4 bytes characters (U+10000 to U+10FFFF), which might screw up everything.

- string length is counted in characters and a 4 byte character is probably only counted as 1 character, so any length*2 calculations are incorrect
- `du` might stop at characters which end on `00 00`

So, how safe is it to use such scripts debugging .NET applications in WinDbg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short version: yes, it is safe to do string calculations in WinDbg using `String.Length` and it is safe to use `du` to dump them.

### UTF-16 4 byte characters ending on 00 00

The unicode specification defines that the first 6 bits of byte 1 are  110110 and the first 6 bits of byte 3 are  110111. This means that the first nibble (4 bits) is always a `D` so that a 4 byte UTF-16 character always looks like this: `D? ?? D? ??` and will never end with `00 00`.

Therefore it is safe to use `du` commands on UTF-16 strings.

### Using string.Length for calculating the range

Before answering my own question, I wanted to try the behavior in C# and therefore asked the [question about how to create 4-byte characters in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20874428/defining-4-byte-utf-16-character-in-a-string).

Unexpectedly, this already pointed me to the answer: string.Length is the string length in code units, not characters. To get the Unicode character length, we should use the `System.Globalization.StringInfo` class.